# Creative way to monitor an OCDB Access VBA app as a Service

Tags: ms-access, vba, odbc

I've got an Access VBA application that is responsible for querying a SQL table once per second over ODBC, looking for records where processed = 0. When it finds one, it will process an Access report and print it to PDF using CutePDF, saving it to a network drive that our desktop application (that added the SQL record with processed = 0) can access, opening it on the user's desktop.

I've spent considerable time debugging this, my first VBA application, and have all errors being trapped & logged. This morning, the Access application was closed, so no reports were being processed. Opening the .accdb allowed the backlog of reports to begin processing. The error log is empty, and the server has not rebooted in nearly a month.

As far as I know, this application should ONLY be run from a desktop, so an administrator must log into the server after a reboot. I've read that running MSACCESS as a service is a "terrible idea" and exposes Windows to corruption if Access errors out.

That's the state of things. Here are my questions.

- Is there a pre-written application you would recommend that I install
  on this server to monitor & log the events of the application
  (particularly, exits & opens)?
- As a last resort, I suppose I could
  add a function that, every 10 minutes, writes to a "status log" text
  file that basically says, "I am here!" so that I can at least find
  out WHEN an app closed, if not WHY. This seems like overkill, as the log file could grow enormous unless I create & destroy it every 5-10 minutes instead of appending it.

You'll have to forgive me, prior to this app I worked exclusively on PHP & JavaScript, and haven't taken a Visual Basic or C-based class since college 6 years ago.

Any creative solutions?

Comment: When you query for `processed = 0` update/overwrite a field in another table with the current time? This could be checked by the partner application

Answer (score 0):

My 1st thought is use the Profiler to capture what you need.
Does your app reset the processed = 0 flags when the reports are created?
You could have a 1 record table with a 'last processed' date field, and just update that everytime it runs.